# get a udv from include controller to test plan

Tags: jmeter

I need to get a variable created in a test fragment through JSON extractor into a test plan. Thrown with 'MissingPropertyException' in the test plan.

> javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Invoices for class: Script117
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
>       at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]

I have tried to use the jsr223 processor in the test plan to access the variable.

The groovy script in jsr223 is like

```
if (vars.get(Invoices.size() == 0))
AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("no Invoice present");
```

Comment: What is Invoices value? What are you trying to check?

Comment: Invoices is a variable which stores json extracted through json extractor. It can have some value or nothing(null), something like below

Comment: {"Invoices":[],"TotalPageCount":0,"TotalRecordCount":0}

Comment: {"Invoices":[{"Balance":192.46,"DueDate":"2019-06-13T06:34:01.000Z","EndDate":"2019-06-13T06:34:01.000Z","InvoiceId":40001015,"InvoiceNumber":"45641231","IssueDate":"2019-06-13T06:34:01.000Z","OutstandingBalance":192.46,"StartDate":"2019-06-13T06:32:13.000Z"}],"TotalPageCount":0,"TotalRecordCount":0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you need to check if the invoices is blank then fail.

Please check the below plan if that helps:-
Below is json extractor to fetch invoices.
[image]

Below fetched values are used.
[image]
Assertion to check if invoices is not blank.
[image]
Below is the output. If the invoices is blank then it will fail the request.
[image]

Hope this helps.

**Update:-**
Below is a plan with test fragment. To pass variable use like ${varInvoices}
[image]

**Update2:-**

Json config:-
[image]
First test fragment:-
[image]
2nd Test Fragment:-
[image]
Output:-
[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, the flow is same expect that the 'Invoices' variable is created in a separate test fragment (separate jmx file which has no thread) and used in a test plan by adding that test fragment as 'Test Fragment' element

Comment: Having issues while calling the variable from test fragment, 'vars.get' is not working. Debug sampler proves the variable is populated.

Comment: Please check the update if that helps. Fetch variable directly using ${varInvoices}..

Comment: I have tried with Module controller and that is also working with S{varInvoices}

Comment: Can you please update screen shot by pointing to JSON Extractor, also can you try the same with 2 jmx files involved, in case use Include Controller to point to the test fragement. thanks

Comment: Please check the update2. Hope that helps. If it is not what you expect. Please share your test plan for clarity.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I solved this with by using module controller, which contains the include controller,if condition which contains jsr223 sampler and jsr223 assertion with condition;  ${__javaScript(${Invoices} == "")}. This solved my problem.